# iOS 5 issues: Navigation bar clipped after dismissing modal

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, clipping, ios5

I have a nice little app on the app store that does pretty well for itself. Life was great until iOS 5 came to town. Now, I have a number of issues with my app that I have no way of fixing because I have no clue what is going on, because I feel that they are iOS 5 issues, not mine.

Was there an iOS 5 conversion manual I missed? Or did they just change everything for fun, and want us to figure out where all the easter eggs were?

Here is another issue I am experiencing (that I have wasted so much time trying to fix), that DON'T EXIST AT ALL when I simply say that I want to run the app in good ol' 4.2:

Modal view

My app is a simple reader app. I have a book reading view that displays text with a UIWebView. One of the features I have been working on involves the ability to take notes as you read. This is achieved by hitting a button, and presenting a modal view. Yes, a modal view. The most simple pre- iOS 5 thing you could possibly do. Now, when I dismiss my modal view, just by hitting cancel, and simply dismiss the view, when I get back to my reader view, the navigation bar at the top is pushed up half way off the screen! This doesn't happen in 4.2, but there it is in iOS 5!

What can I do to get this issue resolved?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is part one of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259601/ios-5-issues-disappearing-keyboard-when-pulling-up-a-uitextview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was just able to figure out what in the blazes was going on. I had the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation value set to a BOOL variable, so that when the modalView was coming back, it didn't know the state/size of the status bar. Fixed that, and the problem disappeared.

Comment: How's that? You were returning YES on every shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling it has something to do with the way you present and dismissing the modalview. Apple introduced a new method to present views. May you try using theses instead of the old ones and see if it fixes your problem.

So here is what you do:

change this method:

```
presentModalViewController:animated:
```

into the new preferred method introduced with iOS 5:

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

Depending if you are using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`to dismiss your view, change it into `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`.

This methods also have completion handler which is very useful to do some extra work after the view has been presented/dismissed. Maybe that also helps with your other issue. Let me know if that might helped.

Comment: Hey d., I appreciate your answer very much. I went ahead and updated my present/dismiss methods, (with nil as the block), and it didn't fix anything unfortunately. Do I need to be running a block? What should I be doing in it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A major change in iOS 5 is that the `navigationController` property of UIViewController is no longer set for modal views.  Instead, there is a new (not present in iOS 4) `parentViewController` property.  So where you're using `navigationController` in a modal view you need to change the logic to something like:

```
UIViewController* parent;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(parentViewController)]) {
    parent = self.parentViewController;
}
else {
    parent = self.navigationController;
}
```

(That's from memory, so I can't guarantee that every t is dotted and every i crossed.)

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks. I didn't know about the change. I'm a bit confused on the context of where I need to be using the above code. Instead of calling [self presentView...], I insert your code and call [parent presentView...]? Thanks for your help, I would really love to get these issues ironed out.

Comment: No, basically any place where you refer to "navigationController" you'd insert the above.  If you don't use UIViewController's "navigationController" property then the above doesn't apply (though certainly there are several other significant changes in the UI).  (It's worth reviewing the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html) in order to see the 10% of the changes that Apple actually documented.)

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this same clipping problem.

I found out that the reason for my issue was that I set the content size within the modal dialog (something I did for my iPad layout), so removing these two lines seemed to fix the issue:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size;
```

I thought the problem was fixed but it wasn't. After reviewing the code some more, cleaning the build, and retesting it turned out to be a `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` which would return NO for all orientations, for a brief amount of time (`flag == NO`) while the app is loading (root controller). You want to at least return YES to one orientation like so:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return !self.flag ? UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait == toInterfaceOrientation : YES;
}
```